# How to convert sine transformed vector back to original

Tags: trigonometry

Using R, if I have
`x <- sin(1:10)`
Which function do I use to get these values back to 1:10 again?

Comment: This question is best suitable for [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: How do I move it to stackoverflow?

Comment: You can re-post this as a new question on SO, and delete the question from here.

Comment: I am blocked from deleting this post, but I did create the new one at SO:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63307056/how-to-convert-sine-transformed-vector-back-to-original

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is actually impossible, regardless of programming language. This is because $x=\sin y$ doesn't tell us the value of $y$. In particular, there's no way to distinguish $y=10$ from infinitely many other values. With that said, the arcsine function's R implementation [is named](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Trig) `asin`.

Comment: What if I know the original values still?

Comment: @ScubaSteve What do you mean?

Comment: Could I apply a function to them and combine it with the sine output to recover?

Comment: @As I said, no. If you want access to both variables, first write `y<-1:10`, then `x<-sin(y)` on the next line. This is called variable caching.